# How to call the two distinct points on a heart-shaped curve

Tags: single-word-requests, shapes

A heart shape as it is usually drawn (♥) consists of two smooth curve segments which join at two points, one at the top and one at the bottom. What is the most concise way to refer to these points?

I think *cusps* might be the right expression, but how do I call them in order to avoid ambiguity between the two? I thought about using *convex* and *concave cusp*, but then realized being convex or concave is relative to whether you look at the curve from the inside or from the outside.

Comment: Perhaps better asked on Math?

Comment: Neat (and relevant) animation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardioid.

Comment: Are you looking for a mathematical term or a common term?

Comment: @choster I'm looking for the common term but a mathematical term would be a nice extra

Comment: To avoid ambiguity, provide a diagram with the cusps labeled A and B, and refer to them as Cusp A and Cusp B thereafter.  :-)

Comment: IMO, hearts only have one cusp; the other is a vertex. Both terms are largely interchangeable, and I may be technically incorrect, but I'd know exactly which you meant if said as such.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct in that the term for this is a [cusp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cusp_(singularity)).  (See also [cardioid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardioid) curve).

As far as differentiating the upper one from the lower one, well, why not *upper* and *lower*?

Answer (score 4):

This is indeed called a *[cusp](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cusp)*. Two senses of that definition work well at the same time:  the intersection of two curves, in general; and the reflection of a curve on itself.

You are right about the difficulty of *convex* or *concave*.  For purely conversational English you might try *internal* and *external*, or for the heart shape *per se*, *upper* and *lower* would probably be generally understood.